# Mosfet controlled LED-strip is dimmed

Tags: arduino, led, mosfet

I'm gonna start to excuse me for my bad soldering/layout, but this is [image: my project].

[image]

I am using a mosfets (IRF520) to which I have connected a 12V power source to the drain and source. They are connected up to a led strip. The gate I am controlling with my arduino MKR1000 (3.3v outputs). The circuit does exactly what I expect from it except for one thing: the leds dont burn as bright as I would expect. When I connect a 12v input to the gate they do burn as bright as I expect. My guess is that it is because the voltage I put on the gate is too low, and the mosfets are acting as a variable resistance.

The store I bought them though tells me that they should burn as bright with 3.3v as with 12v. Am I doing something wrong, or am I using the wrong mosfets?

Schematic I used:

[image]

Link to datasheet:
https://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/91017.pdf

Comment: There is a schematic tool button on the editor toolbar. Please add a schematic so we know what you are describing.

Comment: And link to the IRF520 datasheet.

Comment: @Terabyte: That's not a schematic - it's a wiring diagram. It shows how the bits are wired up but not the "scheme" or how it's supposed to work. A schematic shows symbols for the transistors, etc., showing their gate, drain and source. In this case you'll probably get away with it but generally those diagrams are frowned upon (gross understatement).

Comment: _The store I bought them though tell me that they should burn as bright with 3.3v as with 12v._ This is sellers' talk, this is not true. All the led strips that I already saw had a resistor for each section of leds, and as the resistor is the same, the led's bright will not be the same with 3.3v or 12v. Try connecting the 12v directly to the strip, and see if the source really withstands all this strip.

Comment: @Transistor My apologies, but I am a proper beginner :)

Comment: If you're powering LED strips, they need to see 12V and ideally 13.8V (automotive generator voltage while running).

Comment: Your wiring cartoon shows inconsistent connections for those 10 kOhm resistors. Probably they shoud all be between G and S of the mosfets. But  the reason for poor performance is elsewhere, because in the photo they seem to be assembled right and their effect as wrongly connected would be neglible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Vgs is too low. You could easily check this by connecting the gate to VUSB or even the 12V as you did. I used IRF520 with 3.3V logic and had to use a higher voltage transistor coupling to the gate to increase Vgs.

Comment: To be honest, i'd prefer to replace the mosfet with another one that will work with 3.3v. Do you by any chance have a suggestion for a replacement mosfet?

Comment: I guess you want through hole?

Comment: What do you mean by "through hole"?

Comment: I googled it, and my answer is yes :)

Comment: Like the one you have on your board. For mounting in a hole. Not surface mount. Anyhow: IRLZ44N or IRF3708